# How to manually change the end of function and extend it in IDA pro?

Tags: ida

So in a malware sample (Shelter) IDA doesn't include some parts of the function in the function itself, and puts the endp in an earlier part, so for example the function really ends at 0x401080 but it thinks it ends at 0x401050 for some reason even tho the last instruction isn't ret and its just a SUB instruction, and the next instruction is a valid and instruction and I'm not sure why its not detecting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the function name -> "Edit function..." -> "End address" field

There you can edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Select an address, then type "E".

This will set the address as the end of the function that exists before it.